# Mongodb fetch page from specific record

Tags: mongodb

I have a database with many record, say `events`.
I want to fetch up to 100 events who's type is "click", and all the events in between. this means that the result will probably be more than 100 events, but it will have no more than 100 "click" events.

Add to that that I need the query to start from a specific point (given by event id).

For example:

`1 click
2 drag
3 drag
4 click
5 click
6 drop
7 click
8 click
9 click`

If I ask the db to fetch up to 4 "click" events (and all the events in between), starting from event 4. should return:

`4 click
5 click
6 drop
7 click
8 click`

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea that comes to my mind. Unfortunately, it consists of two queries:

```
var clickDoc = db.events.find({"type": "click"}).sort({"_id": 1}).skip(99).limit(1)[0];
db.events.find({"_id": {$lte: clickDoc._id}}).sort({"_id": 1})
```